# Visual Basic - Display forename and surname from value of max

Tags: vb.net

Last question for my visual basic learning.

In my code I have read in a `.csv` file of 30 users. I determine how many users have completed a maximum of jumps. There are about 3 users that have about 120 jumping jacks.

I am trying to display these user in a list box in my DisplayMaxJumpers procedure.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Variables for each user
        Dim entryID(30) As String
        Dim location(30) As String
        Dim forename(30) As String
        Dim surname(30) As String
        Dim jumps(30) As Integer
        Dim bibValues(30) As String
        Dim maxJumps As Integer

        'Define Calls and Functions
        Call LoadAthletes(entryID, location, forename, surname, jumps)
        Call CreateBibValues(bibValues, forename, surname, location)
        Call FindMaxJumps(maxJumps, jumps)
        Call DisplayMaxJumpers(maxJumps, forename, surname, jumps)
        Call TallyAthletes()

    End Sub

    'Get details from reading a file
    Private Sub LoadAthletes(ByRef entryID As String(), ByRef location As String(), ByRef forname As String(), ByRef surname As String(), ByRef jumps As Integer())
        Dim filename As String
        filename = "C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\athletes.csv"
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
        For counter = 1 To 30
            Input(1, entryID(counter))
            Input(1, location(counter))
            Input(1, forname(counter))
            Input(1, surname(counter))
            Input(1, jumps(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub
    'Creates the BibValues and saves it to disk
    Private Sub CreateBibValues(ByVal bibValues As String(), ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal location As String())
        'local var to determine Ascii converstion and what character to convert
        Dim locationAscii(30) As Integer
        Dim firstCharacter(30) As String
        'Loop to assign Bib Values
        For counter = 1 To 30
            firstCharacter(counter) = forename(counter).Substring(0, 1)
            locationAscii(counter) = Asc(location(counter))
            bibValues(counter) = firstCharacter(counter) & surname(counter) & locationAscii(counter)
        Next
        'Save bibValues.csv to disk
        Dim savedFile As String
        savedFile = ("C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\bibValues.csv")
        FileOpen(1, savedFile, OpenMode.Output)
        For counter = 1 To 30
            PrintLine(1, bibValues(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub
    'Function to find max jumps
    Public Function FindMaxJumps(ByVal maxJumps As Integer, ByVal jumps As Integer())
        maxJumps = jumps(1)
        For counter = 2 To 30
            If jumps(counter) > maxJumps Then
                maxJumps = jumps(counter)
            End If
        Next

        Return maxJumps
    End Function

    'Determines if current number of jumps equals max jumps and displays forenameand surname
    Private Sub DisplayMaxJumpers(ByVal maxJumps As Integer, ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal jumps As Integer())




    End Sub
    ' Displays how many finalists by location 
    Private Sub TallyAthletes()



    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So first question is what have you tried.  Next question would be how set are you on using arrays for this.  A much cleaner option would be to define a class for your Athletes which have properties for Surname, forename etc, then have a single list of all your athletes, meaning doing things like selecting the top x is a comparatively simple process

Comment: As @Hursey says, you need to get your head around classes and objects. There's plenty of instructional material out there to get through before you seek assistance here I think.

Comment: I know using a class is the way. But array's are the assignment. So I am pretty sold on that. My expertise is Swift not VB. This my son's homework that I am trying to help him with.

Comment: If you have programming expertise then we shouldn't have to tell you that you should work out the logic first and then implement that logic in code. What is your logic, exactly what step in that logic are you having trouble with and what code do you have to implement the previous steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to add an item to a listbox control

```
Private Sub DisplayMaxJumpers(ByVal maxJumps As Integer, ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal jumps As Integer())

    Listbox1.Items.add(Forename & " " & Surname & " Scored " & Jumps & "/" & Maxjumps)

End Sub
```

If you struggle to acces the variables, this is because you declared them inside another method.

you can fix it by making it public, placing a list

```
' Store a list of Users, shared between all methods
public Users as new list(of UserProfile)

' Define what variables each userprofile can contain
public class UserProfile
   public Forname as string 
   public surname as string 
   public Jumps as integer 
end class

public sub Example()

' Add an example user to the list
Users.add(new user with {.forename = "John", .surname = "Jehnson", .Jumps = 3})

' Find the user again
dim UserResult as UserProfile = Users.where(function (c) c.forename = "John").first

'  and Display it in a listbox
listbox1.items.add(UserResult.Forename & " scored " & UserResult.Jumps & " jumps")
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the public class is beyond the scope of the course. I have had about 3 weeks to try to learn VB in order to help my son pass the practical side of his exam. This code represents the course material. Really weird that the teacher does not allow using classes. Your answer helps me to be able explain it enough so he can complete it.